# Android Gradle build fails dexBuilderDebug task, after updating to Kotlin 1.4

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, gradle, firebase-performance

I've tried to update my Android project to Kotlin `1.4.0`, since it's now oficially stable, and after update I've encountered a problem. I will not post the entire stack here, since it's very long, but the mot top part of it looks like this:

```
...
> Task :app:transformClassesWithFirebasePerformancePluginForDebug
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart
> Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource
> Task :app:dexBuilderDebug FAILED
org.gradle.workers.WorkerExecutionException: There was a failure while executing work items
...
```

Looking for a cause, lower in the stack, I've found this:

```
...
Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to process: 
/bitrise/src/app/build/intermediates/transforms/FirebasePerformancePlugin/debug/0, 
/bitrise/src/app/build/intermediates/transforms/FirebasePerformancePlugin/debug/1,
/bitrise/src/app/build/intermediates/transforms/FirebasePerformancePlugin/debug/2
...
```

Which directs me to the conclusion, that Firebase Performance library cannot be build correctly. I'm using Firebase Performance version `19.0.8` with gradle classpath plugin version `1.3.1`. I have not changed it for a while, and reverting to earlier versions does not resolve the issue. The last error registered on stack is this:

```
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:151)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:118)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dexing.DexWorkActionKt.process(DexWorkAction.kt:194)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected non-class file: META-INF/versions/9/kotlin/reflect/jvm/internal/impl/serialization/deserialization/builtins/BuiltInsResourceLoader.class
```

I've determined, that removing Firebase Performance library and reverting back to Kotlin `1.3.71` resolves the problem, but I'd like to keep them both for future of the project, so I'm looking for other solution.

My `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
apply from: "dependencies.gradle"
apply from: "buildtypes.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 100
        versionName "1.0.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        archivesBaseName = "$applicationId-$versionName-$versionCode"
    }

    compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }

    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding = true
    }
}
```

And a complete list of dependencies:

```
    coreLibraryDesugaring "com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:$versions.coreDesugaring"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "androidx.core:core:$versions.core"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:$versions.core"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$versions.appCompat"
    implementation "androidx.browser:browser:$versions.browser"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$versions.constraintLayout"
    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:$versions.legacy"

    // UI
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$versions.material"
    implementation "com.appyvet:materialrangebar:$versions.materialRangeBar"
    implementation "com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:$versions.datetimepicker"

    // Lifecycle
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$versions.lifecycle"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$versions.lifecycle"

    // Navigation component
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigation_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigation_version"

    // Coroutines
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$versions.coroutines"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$versions.coroutines"

    // Koin
    implementation "org.koin:koin-android:$versions.koin"
    implementation "org.koin:koin-androidx-ext:$versions.koin"
    implementation "org.koin:koin-androidx-scope:$versions.koin"
    implementation "org.koin:koin-androidx-viewmodel:$versions.koin"

    // Work Manager
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:$versions.work"
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$versions.work"

    // Flipper
    debugImplementation "com.facebook.soloader:soloader:$versions.soloader"
    debugImplementation "com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:$versions.flipper"
    debugImplementation "com.kgurgul.flipper:flipper-realm-android:$versions.flipperRealm"
    debugImplementation "com.facebook.flipper:flipper:$versions.flipper"
    releaseImplementation "com.facebook.flipper:flipper-noop:$versions.flipper"

    // Location & Maps
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$versions.playLocation"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$versions.playLocation"
    implementation "com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:$versions.mapUtils"

    // Logging
    implementation "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:$versions.timber"
    implementation "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:$versions.slf4j"
    implementation "com.github.tony19:logback-android:$versions.logback"

    // Databases
    implementation "com.github.sevar83:android-spatialite:$versions.spatialite"

    // Archives
    implementation "org.zeroturnaround:zt-zip:$versions.ztZip"

    // Dialogs
    implementation "com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:$versions.materialDialogs"
    implementation "com.afollestad.material-dialogs:datetime:$versions.materialDialogs"
    implementation "com.afollestad.material-dialogs:lifecycle:$versions.materialDialogs"

    // Permissions
    implementation "com.karumi:dexter:$versions.dexter"
    implementation("dev.doubledot.doki:library:$versions.doki") {
        transitive = true
    }

    // JSON
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi:$versions.moshi"
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:$versions.moshi"

    // Firebase
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:$firebase_versions.analytics"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:$firebase_versions.crashlytics"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:$firebase_versions.performance"

    // Payments
    implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:$versions.billing"
    implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing-ktx:$versions.billing"

    // Testing
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$test_version.junit"
    testImplementation "androidx.test:core:$test_version.androidTest"
    testImplementation "androidx.test:runner:$test_version.androidTest"
```

Why is this build failing? Is it Kotlin's `1.4.0` fault, or is there something wrong with dependencies? Can this issue be solved without reverting to previous Kotlin version?

Comment: if you use `1.3.72` then?

Comment: i don't know why this got downvoted so i upvoted you: we're also having issues with 1.4 and just staying on 1.3 forever isn't going to work.  for your case, try doing a ./gradlew clean - we'll post our fix when we figure it out

Comment: When using `1.3.72` everything works fine. I've done clean rebuilds, and nothing seems to help.

Comment: Here is the issue: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1888

Comment: We're seeing this issue too, staying to 1.3 is not really a solution, do you have any updates?

Answer (score 3):

Not the best solution but at least for me, it worked:
If you are building from command line using the Gradle wrapper:

```
./gradlew clean assembleDebug -Pdisable-performance-plugin
```

If you run your project from Android Studio:

[image]

Then you are able to run your project using Kotlin 1.4 until they fix the issue.

As a side effect, build times seem to be improved.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be an AGP issue which is going to be addressed in version 4.1.0. More details are here - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/165535092

As a workaround would suggest to apply 4.1.0-rc02
Update

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0-rc02'
```

Comment: I changed import with this but I'm getting an error; This version of the Android Support plugin for IntelliJ IDEA (or Android Studio) cannot open this project, please retry with version 4.1 or newer.

Comment: Yeah, you should bump Android Studio as well @CaferMertCeyhan. It was Android Studio 4.1 RC 2 at the moment of writing the answer. At the moment it's AS 4.1 (release channel)